# Открытие Dialog по нажатию на TextInputLayout

Tags: java, android, kotlin, material

У меня есть TextInputLayout который отвечает за время. Я хочу, чтобы по нажатию на TextInputLayout у меня не выдвигалась клавиатура, а открывался диалог, в котором можно выбрать время. Вопрос не в том, как открыть диалог, а как сделать так, чтобы клавиатура не выдвигалась и еще хотелось бы, чтобы был ripple эффект у TextInputLayout. Проще говоря, мне нужен TextInputLayout с функционалом Button

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:id="@+id/startTimeLayout"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/image_clock"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                style="@style/Theme.BookingManager.TextInputEditText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Начало"
                android:textColor="@color/primary"
                android:text="13:00"
                android:inputType=""/>


        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

По идее вам должно подойти такое решение - перекрыть `TextInputLayout` простой `View`, которой прописать `android:clickable="true"`. Так у вас `View` не будет пропускать клики вниз и при этом на неё можно повесить слушатель нажатий, который уже и будет показывать нужный вам диалог.